# Use of ESSCertIDv2 in a RFC 3161 Timestamp

Tags: timestamp, rfc, eidas

A qualified trust service provider under eIDAS uses ESSCertIDv2 for their time stamp tokens, but ESSCertIDv2 was not present in the [RFC 3161](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3161) specification, it was added later in [RFC 5816](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5816).

RFC 3161 in 2.4.2 requires ESSCertID:

> The certificate identifier (ESSCertID) of the    TSA certificate MUST
> be included as a signerInfo attribute inside a    SigningCertificate
> attribute.

Can a token that uses ESSCertIDv2 instead of ESSCertID be a valid RFC 3161 time stamp token?

Can it be used as a qualified time stamp under eIDAS?

Answer (score 0):

> Can a token that uses ESSCertIDv2 instead of ESSCertID be a valid RFC 3161 time stamp token?

Yes. As per §[2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5816#section-2.1) of RFC 5816, "[i]f the certReq field is present and set to true, the TSA's public key certificate that is referenced by the ESSCertID [ESS] field ... **or by the ESSCertIDv2 [ESSV2] field** ... MUST be provided by the TSA ..."

> Can it be used as a qualified time stamp under eIDAS?

Hmm, yes obviously. (Hope I haven't misunderstood the question.)